# How to exact difference between 2 dates in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-math

I want to find difference between 2 dates in php.But I am not getting exact difference.
please help me.
The output I must get as "2 years 0 months 0 days".
But I am getting as "1 years 12 months and 4 days".
where I am wrong?

```
$createddate="2015-12-24";

//find difference between the dates present-createddate of user
     $now = time(); // present time 
     $your_date = strtotime($createddate);

   $difference = abs($now - $your_date);
   echo $difference;

     // Years, months and days version
$years = floor($difference / (365*60*60*24));
//echo $years;
$months = floor(($difference - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
//echo $months;
$days = floor(($difference - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
//echo $days;
$membersince .= $years.' years '.$months.' months and '.$days.' days';
```

Comment: Use DateTime objects, and the diff() method. This gets asked a lot. I'll find a duplicate in no time searching... you should do so too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-12-24');
$interval  = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed   = $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days');
echo $elapsed;
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/Ge1Pp)