# Compare date in a table to todays date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datepicker

Im trying to figure out how can I make an if statement to compare todays date with a date field in a table.

```
<?php 
    $dayte_today = date('Y-m-d');
    $plannerid = $_GET["plannerid"];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM planner_content WHERE planner_id='$plannerid'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count>=1){ 
    /* echo "Your id is $userID"; */
        while ($link =  mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        echo ''.$link->date.' - '.$link->comment.'' ;
        }

    }
    else {
        echo "No events yet";
    }
?>
```

I've got it to show results for the moment, but I don't know how to compare the actual date with the date in the table. I tried to use mysqli_fetch_object but I didn'y get it to work.

Comment: I would convert all database dates to a unix timestamp using strtotime() and then use time() to get the current time as a timestamp....then compare

Comment: i dont need time i just want to compare a date such as 09/09/2014

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847762/689579

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

For comparing dates, you can use the combination of date() and strtotime functions

```
if($count>=1){ 
    /* echo "Your id is $userID"; */
        while ($link =  mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $planned_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($link->date));
        /* Do your comparison here */
           $dayte_today - $planned_date;
        }

    }
    else {
        echo "No events yet";
    }
```

You can also filter from the mysql query using a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM planner_content WHERE planner_id='$plannerid' AND date < curdate();
```

Comment: i want it in the if function , to "echo" only the past dates

Comment: In that case, you can just filter from the sql query. Check the update to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare dates using [mysql's built-in date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)?

Add a column to your select statement that uses `datediff()` to return a number that you can use in your application logic.