# Comparing date by php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to compare two dates, the first is my current date and the second is a date from database.

When I see both of them they looks identical, but PHP gives me another result. I tried to compare using functions like `strcmp`. I simplified my code so you can understand it easier.

```
<?php
$users_day = "20".date("y-m-d");
$looper = 0 ;
$all_users_selection = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
while($user_rows = mysql_fetch_array($all_users_selection) )
{
    if($user_rows['user_lastseen'] != NULL)
    {
        //Getting user lastseen day and hour
        $db_user_date[$looper] = substr(($user_rows['user_lastseen']) ,0 , 10);
        $db_user_curr[$looper] = $user_rows['username'];
        //Comparing day then hour
        if (strcmp($users_day,$db_user_date[$looper]) != 0)
        {
            //Set offline
            $current_user_update = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_status = 'offline' WHERE username = '$db_user_curr[$looper]'");
        }
        $looper++;
  }
  ?>
```

When I try to test variables, for example `echo $users_day;`, it gives my the `2016-12-24` (my current date) .

Also when I test the dates from database it gives me a date with the same type for example I added:

```
echo $db_user_date[$looper];
```

In my `while loop` and in some case the date was identical `2016-12-24`
when i tested `echo strcmp($users_day,$db_user_date[$looper]);`
it gives me -10 which means they are 100% different but they are not!

Any idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3847736/5695475 here is a similar question with many answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your dates to time, which is a numeric value, then compare them.

```
$current = strtotime($users_day)
$db_date = strtotime($db_user_date[$looper])

if($current > $db_date)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: it works , thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When comparing dates, you should comapre their values, not their string representation.
String `'01 Jan 2017'` is not equal to string `'2017-01-01'`, however, dates are actually equal, right?

Therefore, you need to transform both dates-string into one format so you can compare them safely. The answer by Hicaro handles the problem easily.

Also, consider replacing this *whole* block of code with a single query:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_status = 'offline' WHERE DATE(user_lastseen) <> CURDATE()");
```

So you're setting 'offline' status to all users whose `user_lastseen` is not equal to today (I assume this is what you're trying to achieve?).