# why strtotime isn't working on php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to compare between two date but unfortunately this isn't working by converting this into UNIX format with `strtotime`. I'm trying to **compare** a date to another date.

**However this format is working:**

```
if(strtotime("22-04-17") < strtotime("25-05-17")){
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}
```

But Many times it's failing. I've seen a lot of examples on the web but I can't figure out anything good!

```
if(strtotime("22-04-17") < strtotime("04-05-17")){ //passing still the 
    // bigger on but not working
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates)

Comment: default format for `strtotime` is `Y-m-d`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That is actually very complex to understand. I'm just simply trying to compare between two date. So please give me a easier example.

Comment: _Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed._ -- From [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @AbraCadaver The first one example is working. But the second one isn't working. but still the second is also greater.

Comment: Use 4 digit years to disambiguate or use `YY-mm-dd`

Comment: 2nd is not greater because on this comparison, you are basically testing if year 22 is less than year 04.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (make special note of the part I've put in **bold**):

> "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. **If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.**"

So here's what you're doing, with the dates PHP is interpreting your strings as in comments:

```
// Is 17 April 2022 earlier than 17 May 2025? Yes.
if(strtotime("22-04-17") < strtotime("25-05-17")){
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}

// Is 17 April 2022 earlier than 17 May 2004? No.
if(strtotime("22-04-17") < strtotime("04-05-17")){ //passing still the 
    // bigger on but not working
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}
```

I hope this makes the problem you're having clear.

As it also says in the manual, use `DateTime::createFromFormat`/`date_create_from_format` if you want to avoid ambiguity:

```
 $date = date_create_from_format('d-m-y', '04-05-17'); // 4 May 2017
```

Comment: Yes, that is elegant to understand the problem. Then how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

your comparsion is not working because `strtotime("22-04-17")` actually results to timestamp for this date: `17th April 2022`;

Do the following and you will see what I mean. the following code will output '2022-May-17`

```
$date = "22-05-17";
echo date ("Y-M-d ",strtotime($date))."<br>";
```

Comment: I'm not here for negotiation. I want a solution, Please help me if you can

Comment: I am not trying to negotiate with you. What I am telling you is why your code is not working. since you have chosen a `-` as separator and your year is in 2 digits, PHP assumes the format as `y-m-d`. The solution here is to use the 4 digit year.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$date1 = date('d-m-y',strtotime("22-04-17"));
$date2 = date('d-m-y',strtotime("04-05-17"));;

if((int)strtotime($date1) < (int)strtotime($date2)){ //passing still the  
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}
```

Your year format `17` causing the problem in `strtotime` function

Comment: This one is working !! I don't know if there is a bug. Did you use this on production?

Comment: @CodeCooker instead of `date('d-m-y',strtotime("22-04-17"));` and `date('d-m-y',strtotime("04-05-17"));` You can just put `strtotime("22-04-17 GMT");` and `strtotime("04-05-17 GMT");`

Comment: This is kinda misleading because if you do `$date1 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("22-04-17"));
$date2 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("04-05-17"));
 
if((int)strtotime($date1) < (int)strtotime($date2)){ //passing still the  
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}` this fails.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Yes It is failing.. ! when I'm using this format `m-d-Y` and giving it like `08-15-17` it is generating 1970 year !! which is incredible.

Comment: told you :). So to fix this the best thing you can do is use a 4 digit year. where do you get these dates from anyways? May be you can write a function to turn these into proper days.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you're looking for but have you tried doing this to showing if date greater / smaller?

```
// Dates
$Date1 = strtotime("22-04-17 GMT");
$Date2 = strtotime("04-05-17 GMT");

// Diff between dates
$Diff = (int)floor(($Date1 - $Date2) / (60*60*24));

if ($Diff < 0) {
   echo "The Diff is negative";
}
```

Then the other way is like this answer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550077/3296661)

```
$date1 = strtotime("22-04-17 GMT");
$date2 = strtotime("04-05-17 GMT");

if((int)strtotime($date1) < (int)strtotime($date2)){ //passing still the  
    echo 'Date One is smaller than date two';
}
```

Comment: This one also doesn't look like elegant to me.

Comment: @CodeCooker This is what i use to work out different between dates and also if one greater or smaller. 

You could also use `DateTime` object to check what you need to be honest

Comment: I'm trying to use a date-picker. that could help me to fetch data's from server between two dates in this format `22-04-17` How can I do this, please?

Comment: Check the latest question, someone answered in an elegant way.

Comment: @CodeCooker That is very correct, there is different way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that takes your datestring and properly return timestmp. Please note that I followed PHP's convention of treating 2 digit years, `i.e. 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999`

```
/* functon takes dateString of format dd-dd-yy and return proper timestamp */
function getTimestamp($dateString)
{
    $res = preg_match('/^([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/', $dateString, $matches);
    if(!$res)
        return 0;
    //00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999
    if($matches[3]>=70 &&  $matches[3]<=99 )
        $year = "19".$matches[3];
    else
        $year = "20".$matches[3];
    $formatted_dat_string = $year."-".$matches[2]."-".$matches[1];
    return strtotime($formatted_dat_string);
}
getTimestamp("22-04-99");
```

So you can now use this function instead of `strtotime` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution. The `strtotime()` isn't any good to handle this case. You should go for `dateTime` object instead.

```
//First you need to pass the original format then you will need to pass new 
//Format to get this working properly. Hope this will help you guy's
$myDateTimestart = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateString);
$startDate = $myDateTimestart->format('m-d-Y');
//with Simply that you can format your date properly
```

**I just Messed my times with this thing it was really bad**