# how to understand if one date in php is less than another minus one day?

Tags: php, date

how to understand if one date in php is less than another minus one day? I mean if for example a date is set to "2018/07/**03**"; how can I understand if a given date is less than "2018/07/**02**"

date1 : year1/month1/day1
date2: year2/month2/day2

```
<?php
if ($year1 >= $year2) {
        if ($month1 >= $month2) {
                  if (($day1 - 1) > $day2) {
                      echo 'you could do something..';
                   }
          }
}
?>
```

the above code fails if forexample $year2 = 2017 and $month2 = 11.. can anybody help me? thanks a lot..

Comment: use strtotime();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates)

Comment: but i would like one day less..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime("2018/07/01");
$date2 = strtotime("2018/07/02");

if($date > $date2){
  print('date is bigger');
  // do stuff when date is bigger than date2
} else {
  // else ...
  print('date2 is bigger');
}
```

To convert string to date php has function named `strtotime()`.
Compairing `date` objects is simple.

There is full information about `strtotime()`
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

## Another way:

```
$date = new DateTime("2018/07/01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2018/07/02");


if($date->modify("+1day") > $date2){
  print('date is bigger');
  // do stuff when date is bigger than date2
} else {
  // else ...
  print('date2 is bigger or equal');
}
```

Notice modify modifies **$date** object itself.

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 2):

Here, this should work.

```
$date_to_check = new DateTime($yesterday);
$today = new DateTime();
$time_diff = $today->diff($date_to_check)->d;

if($time_diff > 1) {
echo "This is greater than one day.";
}else{
echo "This is not greater than one day.";
```