# Comparing current date with date from database

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that the 2 dates won't compare or atleast not good.

I tried most of the answers of [Comparing two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates). But none of them was a succes.

**What I have right know:**

```
else if ($_SESSION['org_id'] != "0" && $_SESSION['part_id'] == 0) {
    require '../conn.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `end_date` FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $dUsrId . "'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    if (date('Y-m-d') >= $row['end_date']) {
        header('Location: ../../index');
    } else {
        header('Location: ../../partnersubscription');
    }
}
```

**One of the things I tried**

```
else if ($_SESSION['org_id'] != "0" && $_SESSION['part_id'] == 0) {
    require '../conn.php';
   // header('Location: ../../partnersubscription');
    $sql = "SELECT `end_date` FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $dUsrId . "'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $expire = $row['end_date']; //from database
    $today_time = strtotime($today);
    $expire_time = strtotime($expire);
    if ($expire_time > $today_time) {
        header('Location: ../../index');
    } else {
        header('Location: ../../partnersubscription');
    }
}
```

I expect when the date of today is smaller then the date of the row it will go to index otherwise it will go to partnersubscription.

My row `end_date` looks like this "2019-06-06" and is `DATE`

Comment: Is `end_date` a DATE or a DATETIME data type in your database

Comment: @RiggsFolly DATE

Comment: I would var_dump values just in case if you are getting the right dates, then strtotime them and use > comparison as in the second attempt you made.

Comment: _or at least not good_ What does that mean exactly. Can you provide some dates that dont work? It seems to work for me!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Which one does work for you?

Comment: This `if (date('Y-m-d') >= $row['end_date']) {`

Comment: working fine, here

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ahh I see my mistake thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not to use mysql to check this condition :

```
"SELECT  EXISTS( "SELECT 1 FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $dUsrId . "' AND end_date > NOW() "  ) ;
```

you will get 1 if not expire and 0 if expire 
p.s. you might need to use >= and not only >  ( include or not include today)

Comment: You better be sure that server is using same time zone that is implied by end_date.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `end_date`>=now()  AND `user_id`=$dUsrId;
```

And then check the number of rows if it's 1 then it hasn't expired if it is 0 then it has expired.

Comment: You better be sure that server is using same time zone that is implied by end_date.