# How can i get if early or late?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, time, compare

Here's my code
I want to get if early or late
thank you po

```
 $current_time = strtoupper(date("g:i a "));
             $time = strtoupper(date("g:i a ",strtotime($current_time)));
            //print_r($time);
            
            $start_time = $request->start_time; 
            $s_time = str_replace('/', '-', $start_time);
            $fstart_time= strtoupper(date('g:i a',strtotime($s_time)));
           //print_r($fstart_time);
             
            if ($time > $fstart_time){
                 print_r('early');
             }else{
                 print_r('late');
             }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: what is the format of $start_time ?

Comment: 8:00 PM it depends of the schedule of the students

Comment: update is i fix it i'm happy now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for your format

```
if (time() >= strtotime($request->start_time)) {
    print_r('early');
} else {
    print_r('late');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update i fix my problemm But thank youu in advance

here's my code

```
     $start_time = $request->start_time; 
            $s_time = str_replace('/', '-', $start_time);
            $fstart_time= strtoupper(date('g:i a',strtotime($s_time)));
            print_r($fstart_time);

if (time() >= strtotime($fstart_time)) {
            echo "early";
 } else{

            echo "late";
}
```