# Show "Register" button when registration date is between open/close registration dates

Tags: php

What I need to do is display those returned events that fall between an open and a close date (between a two-week period for example 2022 08 15 to 2022 08 30) and if they do, I want to show and Register button that takes user to a registration page and if it is not true is show the user a Registration button that is not active that says "Registration Not Open". Right now, if one event is true and the rest are false, it will still return all are open for registration by showing the "Register" button for all returned events. The SQL is supposed to return the EventOpenDate (date event registration open) and EventCloseDate (date event registration is closed) and evaluated each returned event separately and show register button if the date falls between when the registration opens and when it is closed.

```
<div class="upcoming-events-area off-white ptb100">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="section-title">Available Sporting Events for Registration 
                     </div>
                         <div class="total-upcoming-event col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                         
                        <?php
                        // Fetching Upcoming events user has NOT signed up for (all-events.php line 69 - Updated 6/25/2021)
                        $isactive=1;
                        $sql = "SELECT 
                                   EventName,
                                   EventLocation,
                                   EventStartDate,
                                   EventEndDate,
                                   EventOpenDate,
                                   EventCloseDate,
                                   EventImage,
                                   id
                                FROM tblevents 
                                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                                    tblbookings.EventId,    
                                    tblbookings.UserId 
                                 FROM tblbookings 
                                 WHERE tblbookings.EventId = tblevents.id 
                                 AND tblbookings.UserId = $_SESSION[usrid])
                                 AND IsActive=:isactive
                                 ORDER BY EventOpenDate DESC";
                                 $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
                                 $query->bindParam(':isactive',$isactive,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                 $query->execute();
                                 $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                                 $cnt=1;
                                     if($query->rowCount() > 0)
                                        {
                                        foreach($results as $row)
                                        { 
                            ?>

                              <div class="single-upcoming shadow-box">
                                 <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm col-xs-12">
                                     <div class="sue-pic">
                                        <img src="admin/eventimages/<?php echo htmlentities($row->EventImage);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlentities($row->EventName);?>" style="border:#000 1px solid"> 
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="sue-date-time text-center">
                                         <span><?php echo htmlentities($row->EventStartDate);?></span>To
                                         <span><?php echo htmlentities($row->EventEndDate);?></span>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="uc-event-title">
                                        <div class="uc-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-globe-alt"></i></div>
                                        <a href="#"><?php echo htmlentities($row->EventName);?></a><br>
                                        <a href="#"><?php if($row > 1) echo ('Pending'); else echo htmlentities($row->BookingStatus);?></a>
                                    </div> 
                                 </div> 
                                 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                     <div class="venu-no">
                                         <p>Location : <?php echo htmlentities($row->EventLocation);?></p>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <?php
                                 if (($currentDate >= $EventOpenDate) && ($EventCloseDate <= $currentDate)){?>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                     <div class="upcoming-ticket text-center">
                                        <a href="event-details.php?evntid=<?php echo htmlentities($row->id);?>" class="btn-def bnt-2 small">Registration</a>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                
                                 <?php }else{ ?>
                                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><?php $eod; ?>
                                     <div class="upcoming-ticket text-center">
                                        <a class="btn-def bnt-2 small">Registration not Open</a>
                                     </div>
                                 </div> 
                                <?php } ?>
                              </div>
                              <?php } }  else { ?>                
                                  <p>No Record Found - (Make sure you are logged in to see the events)</p>    
                                <?php } ?>     
                             <hr />
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Not using $row object with dates?

Comment: Also you didn't declare $currentDate anywhere.

Comment: You check against `$currentDate` but this is not defined in your code. How to check it generally can be found in [How can I compare two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-in-php) P.S. Your H1 is not closed.

Comment: $currentDate = date('YYYY-MM-DD'); is decared earlier in code...<h1 is closed, it is just cut off when I pasted.

Comment: ....the code runs however it is not returning the results that i need.