# My custom-post is considered old even though it is future (ACF) (Wordpress) (php)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made an event system with a custom-post and the ACF plugin for custom fields.

I therefore display my posts only if they are equal to today's date or in the future. All old posts are therefore hidden. This all works very well.

Problem is that when the year is 2024, everything beyond December 31, 2023 is considered old... I know this because when I change my value from `($date_event >= $today)` to `($date_event <= $today)` it displays it to me in my old posts..

I don't understand..

```php
<?php 
                $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'evenement', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'meta_key' => 'start_event', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                $today = date("m-d-Y");
                $date_event = get_field('start_event');
            ?>
                
            <?php if ($date_event >= $today) { ?>
                <?php
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm-d-Y', $date_event );
                    $date_format = $date->format( 'j F Y' );
                    $date_rendu = date_i18n("j F Y", strtotime($date_format));
                ?>

          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">

            <div class="image">
              <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <div class="dates">
                                <?php echo $date_rendu ?>
              </div>
              <div class="nom">
                <?php echo the_title(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>

                    <?php }; ?>
  
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by  "considered old"? Maybe provide a screenshot of your current output ...

Answer (score 0):

Is `$date_event` formatted the same as `$today`, being `m-d-Y`? If it's not the same, try setting the Return Format for that field as `Custom` and inputting `m-d-Y` as the value.

Can also reference another question: [Compare current date as Y-m-d against Y-m-d string which doesn't have zero padded days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/compare-current-date-as-y-m-d-against-y-m-d-string-which-doesnt-have-zero-padde)