# PHP: Check if DateTime isn't expired

Tags: php, datetime, compare

I have a DateTime Object which holds an past timestamp.

I would now like to check if this DateTime is older than for example 48Hours.

How can I compore them best?

Regards

EDIT:
Hi,

thanks for the help.
Heres the helper method.
Any naming suggesstions?

```
    protected function checkTemporalValidity(UserInterface $user, $hours)
{
    $confirmationRequestedAt = $user->getConfirmationTokenRequestedAt();
    $confirmationExpiredAt = new \DateTime('-48hours');

    $timeDifference = $confirmationRequestedAt->diff($confirmationExpiredAt);

    if ($timeDifference->hours >  $hours) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) lets see what I do with the var names

Comment: It formats slightly differently than `date()`, look up on the [DateInterval::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). But beware there's no such member variable as `hours` in `DateInterval`. Please look into the documentation :)

Comment: Hi, I noticed this "bug-canidate" but for first it is ok :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = new DateTime();
$b = new DateTime('-3days');

$diff = $a->diff($b);

if ($diff->days >= 2) {
  echo 'At least 2 days old';
}
```

I used $a and $b for 'testing' purposes. `DateTime::diff` returns a [DateInterval object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), which has a member variable `days` that returns the actual day difference.

Comment: better use (float)$diff->format('%R%a'); instead of $diff->days

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look here:
[How do I compare two DateTime objects in PHP 5.2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8)

The easiest solution therefore would probably be to just create another `DateTime` object that has a date of NOW -48Hours and then compare to that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late, but maybe it helps somebody else:

```
/**
 * Checks if the elapsed time between $startDate and now, is bigger
 * than a given period. This is useful to check an expiry-date.
 * @param DateTime $startDate The moment the time measurement begins.
 * @param DateInterval $validFor The period, the action/token may be used.
 * @return bool Returns true if the action/token expired, otherwise false.
 */
function isExpired(DateTime $startDate, DateInterval $validFor)
{
  $now = new DateTime();

  $expiryDate = clone $startDate;
  $expiryDate->add($validFor);

  return $now > $expiryDate;
}

$startDate = new DateTime('2013-06-16 12:36:34');
$validFor = new DateInterval('P2D'); // valid for 2 days (48h)
$isExpired = isExpired($startDate, $validFor);
```

This way you can also test for other periods than whole days, and it works on Windows servers with older PHP versions too (there was a bug with [DateInterval->days](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184) returning always 6015).

Answer (score 0):

*For people who don't want to work with days...*

You can get a unix timestamp with the [DateTime::getTimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method.
A unix timestamp is in seconds, which is easy to handle. So you can do:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$nowInSeconds = $now->getTimestamp();

$confirmationRequestedAtInSeconds = $confirmationRequestedAt->getTimestamp();

$expired = $now > $confirmationRequestedAtInSeconds + 48 * 60 * 60;
```

`$expired` will be `true` if the time is expired