# PHP: How to compare a time string with date('H:i')?

Tags: php, datetime, comparison

I have time saved in database like 7:30pm as a varchar field. I want to check if this time is greater than time right now or not.

I converted the DB time string into '19:30' and now I want to do something like this:

```
$my_time = '19:30';

if($my_time  > date('H:i'))
{
    do something ...
}
```

The problem is the above will return always true if $my_time is non-empty string.

doing `strtotime($my_time)` is not helping either.

`strtotime('H:i',$my_time)` makes it 00:00 .

doing `(int)date('H:i')` will give 1700 when the actual time is 17:09, so removing colon and then comparing will not work too ....

Changing database time data is out of question in this context.

plz help. Correct me if I stated some facts wrong.

Comment: You should be using the native datetime fields instead of varchar. It would have solved this problem for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8

Comment: i know John... that is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$myTime = '19:30';
if (date('H:i') == date('H:i', strtotime($myTime))) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: A lot of time has passed, but isn't it the same as directly comparing two strings? Since `date()` returns a string, it is exactly as doing: `if(date('H:i') == '19:30')` isn't it?, which is the same thing the OP mentioned trying. That is because `date('H:i', strtotime($myTime))` returns the original $myTime value as string!!! So it is the same as just puting `$myTime` instead of `date('H:i', strtotime($myTime))`.so what is the point? I really don't get it. What am I missing? Why the `if($my_time  > date('H:i'))` the OP suggests supposedly doesn't work? because it DOES work for me.

Comment: question involved how to compare if one is greater than second. not equality comparison only.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct a new [DateTime](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, setting the time on a random date. Than compare those two objects. eg:

```
$my_time = new DateTime('January 1th 1970 19:30');
$comparable_time = new DateTime('January 1th 1970 '. date('H:i'));
if($my_time < $comparable_time) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Please take note of the changelog;

```
Version 5.2.2    DateTime object comparison with the comparison operators changed to work as expected. Previously, all DateTime objects were considered equal (using ==).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the comparison operators with strings like that, because when you do the strings [get converted to numbers first](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

For an one-liner solution, you can use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

```
if(strcmp($my_time, date('H:i')) == 1)
{
    do something ...
}
```

The condition above is semantically equivalent to "if $my_time is greater than the current time", *but only if the format of the strings remains consistent!* **It's very easy to introduce a bug in this code** if for any reason the format of `$my_time` does not directly correspond to the `H:i` pattern.

Dumbing down the values to strings is usually not the way you should be going about using dates and times. A more appropriate solution would be to use the native [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, introduced in PHP 5.2.0 (John Conde has already given an example in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497966/50079)).

However, there is also one possible advantage to treating times as dumb scalar values: the results are consistent with the human perception that 01:00 is always later than 00:00. `DateTime` approaches are dependent on the local timezone and date, and might not always give you the expected results. Example:

```
// assume we are in London
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// assume that today is March 25, 2012
$date1 = new DateTime("2012-03-25 01:00:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2012-03-25 02:00:00");

// and...
if ($date1 == $date2) {
    echo "WTF?!? Equal???";
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Qm83s)**.

The result of this test is different than what comparing some scalar representation of "01:00" and "02:00", so it's a good idea to think about what the proper semantics are for the comparison.

Comment: Its working ...with the India,Kolkata timezone. I guess i can use it on live server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $my_time1);
$date2 = new DateTime();
if ($date1 > $date2)
{
     // do something   
}
```

Comment: +1, and the obligatory disclaimer: The results of this test might be surprising for specific values depending on the current date and timezone.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (H:i) at position 1 (:): Unexpected character' in C:\wamp\www\workspace\bigbite\index_parallel.php on line  ...................and also followed by the warning:  Exception: DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (H:i) at position 1 (:): Unexpected character in C:\wamp\www\workspace\bigbite\index_parallel.php on line

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare strings which represent timestamps. Instead, use `strtotime()` to convert any such strings to Unix timestamps, which are just numbers, and then compare these. You can get the Unix timestamp for the current time with `time()`:

```php
$my_time = '19:30';

if (strtotime($my_time) > time()) {
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Others do not work with > or <