# How can I compare hours:minutes with time variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I wrote the following, however it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

```
$ora_tora = date('H:i', strtotime('+2 hours')); 
     if (($ora_tora >= '00:00') && ($ora_tora < '02:00')) { echo '1'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '02:00') && ($ora_tora < '04:00')) { echo '2'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '04:00') && ($ora_tora < '06:00')) { echo '3'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '06:00') && ($ora_tora < '08:00')) { echo '4'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '08:00') && ($ora_tora < '10:00')) { echo '5'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '10:00') && ($ora_tora < '12:00')) { echo '6'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '12:00') && ($ora_tora < '14:00')) { echo '7'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '14:00') && ($ora_tora < '16:00')) { echo '8'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '16:00') && ($ora_tora < '18:00')) { echo '9'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '18:00') && ($ora_tora < '20:00')) { echo '10'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '20:00') && ($ora_tora < '22:00')) { echo '11'; }
else if (($ora_tora >= '22:00') && ($ora_tora < '00:00')) { echo '12'; }
```

Comment: Works for me... how does it not work? https://3v4l.org/Pj6X8 and https://3v4l.org/r3Dg2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to compare a time string with date('H:i')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497929/php-how-to-compare-a-time-string-with-datehi)

Comment: Other than that you shouldn't have `&& ($ora_tora < '00:00')` in your last `else if` (which to my preference would be `elseif` not `else if`) your code should work fine.

Comment: if all you care about is the hour, why not just get `date('H', ...)`, convert to an int, divide by 2 and add 1?

Comment: @user3783243 if i change it to `date('h:i', strtotime('+2 hours'));` instead of `date('H:i', strtotime('+2 hours'));` then it works, but for AM. However, I want 24h

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all of that with this:

```
echo intdiv(date('G', strtotime('+2 hours')), 2) + 1;
```

'G' is the format for 24 hours without leading 0 (so from 0 to 23)

Comment: Why do you use `intval` and `int` on the same line?

Comment: @Dharman just a personal quirk. I use `intval` for converting strings and cast to int  to convert from float to int.  But right, it could just be removed. Done.

Comment: Ok, better, but still you have one `(int)` left. Why not just do `intdiv()`? Then you do not need to worry about it being a float.

Comment: @Dharman `intdiv` was only introduced in PHP7, this is more generally useful.

Comment: @Nick What is more useful is giving people the push to upgrade to PHP 7, if they haven't done so already. You can't cling on to the past, PHP 5 is dead, move on...

Comment: @Dharman sometimes upgrading is not something you have any control over...

Answer (score 0):

since you actually compare hours you can do:

```
$ora_tora = (int)date('G', strtotime('+2 hours'));
if ($ora_tora > 2 && $ora_tora < 4) {

}
```

Comment: Hi, what happens on 24 (0) ?

Comment: @EnexoOnoma there's no 24. From 23:59 it will go to 00:00 :)

Comment: so from 23 it will go to 0 ?

Comment: I don't really understand how the if condition will end:

`elseif ($ora_tora >= 22 && $ora_tora < 24) { echo '12'; }`

Comment: @EnexoOnoma "so from 23 it will go to 0?" Yes.  24:00 doesn't exist