# How to check a given time string is in between two times in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have given time picker to select time range the user can select start time and end time respectively.

> start time : 11:00 AM    end time : 05:00 PM

which is in 12 hours format, now I want to validate time such as start time should be more than `12:00 AM` and end time should be less than `12:00 PM (11:59 PM)`

Now I'm getting getting time like this:

```
if(strtotime($start_time) > strtotime('12:00 AM') &&  strtotime($end_time) < strtotime('11:59 PM'))
{
  echo "Time Validated";
}
else
{
  echo "Time not validated";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to compare a time string with date('H:i')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497929/php-how-to-compare-a-time-string-with-datehi)

Comment: @bravemaster: It did not solve my issue because it is comparing with current time

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. You show some current code, but don't mention any problems with it; what is it doing or not doing that you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `DateTime` class from given format and compare them to validate time.

Working code is [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/206636d38c591a64f1b97890f03c3d8ee4dcf2dd)
:

```php
function isValidTime($input, $start_time = "`12:00 AM", $end_time = "11:59 PM", $format = "h:i A") {
    $input_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
    $start_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $start_time);
    $end_date = \DateTIme::createFromFormat($format, $end_time);
    return $start_date <= $input_date && $input_date <= $end_date;
}
```

Comment: It would be much nice if you explained how this code works. Code is nice, but it is much better when you actually teach us something and explain why this solution works

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert time to DateTime format using DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $time),
Try like this:

```
$start_time="11:00 AM";
$end_time="05:00 PM";
$formatted_start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $start_time);
$formatted_end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $end_time);
$time1=DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', "12:00 AM");
$time2 =DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', "11:59 PM");

if($formatted_start_time > $time1
   &&  $formatted_end_time < $time2 )
{
  echo "Time Validated";
}
else
{
  echo "Time not validated";
}
```