# Compare 2 date and time not working

Tags: php

I' am comparing date time with today's date time to show or not show the content if its past date. I have checkout this Question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8) but with no success.

**This is the Code**

```
function vacancy_expire($id, $close_date){
        date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");

        $today = "2014-04-30 04:04";
        $close_date = "2014-04-30 16:00";
        if( $today > $close_date ){
           echo "1";
        } else {
           echo "0";
        }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is that you're comparing plain strings. You need to convert them into timestamps and compare the result. Better yet, create DateTime objects and compare that :)

Comment: Okay, let me try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the final code**

```
function vacancy_expire($id, $close_date){
        date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");
        $today = date("Y-m-d H:m");
        $close_date = trim($close_date);
    if( $today > $close_date ){
       return 0;
    } else {
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `<br/>` tag added to the date? you are forcing $today and $close_date to string and even converting it to an invalid date and time

Comment: Sorry, <br/> shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Glad to remove the -1 from the answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the above as follows

```
function vacancy_expire($id, $close_date) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");

    $today = strtotime("2014-04-30 04:04");
    $close_date = strtotime("2014-04-30 16:00");
    if( $today > $close_date ){
       echo "1";
    } else {
       echo "0";
    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not understanding this proposed solution to the reported problem. The function is being passed an argument of `$close_date`, but the parameter value is being ignored. The variables are being set to constant values. The entire body of the function could be replaced with one line: "`echo "0";`".

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the strtotime function here.

$today & $close_date in your function is a string which needs to be converted to date&time.

follow this:

```
<?php

function vacancy_expire($id, $close_date){
    date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");

    $today = time();

    $close_date = strtotime($close_date);

    if( $today > $close_date ){
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
}

vacancy_expire('someid', '2014-04-30 16:00');
```

Here is a [PHP Fiddle](http://3v4l.org/6OdgX) that works for you.

Hope this helps!