# Calculate time difference between pm to am and check if it is in the current time range

Tags: php

Hello i want to check if the current time is between two time range and calculate the difference between them, so far i have this but its not working

```
$current_time = "11:14 pm";
$start_time = "11:00 pm";
$end_time = "07:55 am";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $start_time);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $end_time);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3) {
   echo 'in range';
} else {
    echo 'not in range';
}
```

But it says "not in range"!

Comment: `$date1` and 2 and 3 are not integers

Comment: @Ôrel - DateTime objects explicitly permit this type of comparison, even though they aren't integers.... see the note about comparing objects on this [PHP Docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8

Comment: Your logic is off. `$date1` will be more than `$date2` but it will never be less than `$date3` at the same time. Not with the times you've supplied us. 11:14 pm is NOT LESS than 07:55 am, it's more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When start is after end you need to deal with a day change.

```
$current_time = "11:14 pm"; 
$start_time = "11:00 pm"; 
$end_time = "07:55 am"; 
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time)->getTimestamp(); 
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $start_time)->getTimestamp();; 
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $end_time)->getTimestamp(); 
if ($date3 < $date2) { 
    $date3 += 24 * 3600; 
    if ($date1 < $date2) { 
        $date1 += 24 *3600; 
    } 

} 
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3) { 
   echo 'in range'; 
} else { 
    echo 'not in range'; 
}
```

Comment: Adding the day is the correct solution; but why can't you do this purely with DateTime objects?

Comment: `$current_time = "11:14 pm";
$start_time = "11:00 pm";
$end_time = "07:55 am";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $start_time);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $end_time);

if ($date3 < $date2) {
    $date3->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    if ($date1 < $date2) {
        $date1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}

if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3) {
   echo 'in range';
} else {
    echo 'not in range';
}
`

Comment: Great answer, just one more question how to calculate time difference between current time and end time, ex: current time is 11:30 pm and end time is 7:55 am, i want to get the difference of those two times in minutes, can you help me please? thanks

Comment: with timestamp just do the diff the answer is in second.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your original code is that you are having it create dates from 3 times with unexpected results.

The start of the range is "11:00p" which it assumes means today at 11p.

The end of the range is "7:00a" which is assumes is also today. You actually intend to say "tomorrow at 7:00a".

---

You could try using `strtotime`.

```
$currentTime = strtotime("11:14 pm");
$rangeStart = strtotime("11:00 pm");
$rangeEnd = strtotime("tomorrow 07:55 am");

if ($currentTime >= $rangeStart && $currentTime <= $rangeEnd) {
   echo 'in range';
} else {
    echo 'not in range';
}
```

---

Or you could include actual dates and do something like this:

```
$currentTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2015-01-01 23:14:00");
$rangeStart = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2015-01-01 23:00:00");
$rangeEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2015-01-02 07:55:00");

if ($currentTime >= $rangeStart && $currentTime <= $rangeEnd) {
   echo 'in range';
} else {
    echo 'not in range';
}
```