# How to compare DateTime object with DateTime created from string

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I am trying to perform some updates only if certains conditions are accomplish and one of them is related to comparison between two dates: one obtained from DB and returned by Symfony2 as a DateTime object and the second one get as string from a loop and transformed into a DateTime object.

This is the plain code I was testing:

```
$last = new \DateTime('2015-01-21T19:44:25.000Z');
$current = new \DateTime('2015-06-23 22:10:23');

if ($last > $current) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

That outputs **no**. Now if I try to compare the same in OOP as follow:

```
$lastModifiedAt = new \DateTime($row['LastModifiedDate']);
$lastSyncAt = $entity->getLastSyncAt();

if ($lastModifiedAt > $lastSyncAt) {
    ....
}
```

This is the output of `var_export($lastModifiedAt)` and `var_export($lastSyncAt)`:

```
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2015-06-16 19:23:41.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 2,
   'timezone' => 'Z',
))

DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2015-06-24 07:35:14.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'America/Caracas',
))
```

The execution always enter on the condition, why? what I am doing wrong on the comparison?

**EDIT**

It's weird to me the behavior but perhaps the wrong is my code. Thanks to **@marcin-orlowski** I have run the following test also:

```
var_dump($lastModifiedAt == $lastSyncAt);
var_dump($lastModifiedAt > $lastSyncAt);
var_dump($lastModifiedAt < $lastSyncAt);
```

And this are the results:

```
bool(false)
bool(false) => this is the comparison I am doing
bool(true)
```

So comparison is right, perhaps something else at my code, anyway, thx

Comment: What is the return value of: `var_dump($entity->getLastSyncAt());` ?

Comment: Seeing var_dump($lastModifiedAt) may be good too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two DateTime objects in PHP 5.2.8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent library to handle DateTime related issues .. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon . If the above mentioned case is not the only place you are handling DateTime , then I would consider investing sometime with Carbon.

Answer (score -2):

You can use getTimestamp():

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

And:

```
if ($last->getTimestamp() > $current->getTimestamp()) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, I answered on this [Before Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31026954/1) <<