# Comparing dates php/phpExcel

Tags: php, datetime, phpexcel

I get a date value from an excel file and I change it to date like this

```
$dateEx = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$line)->getValue();      
$date = date('Ymd',($dateEx - 25569)*24*60*60);
```

And I have 2 another date time that I convert from String to date

```
  $dateOuverture = '20150306';
  $dateFerm = '20150906';              

  $dateOuverture = new Datetime($dateOuverture);
  $dateOuverture = $dateOuverture->format('Ymd'); 


  $dateFerm = new Datetime($dateFerm);
  $dateFerm = $dateFerm->format('Ymd');
```

and when I want to compare the date with an if it doesnt works

```
if($date<=$dateFerm && $date>=$dateOuverture){
     echo "Im in the if";

}
```

what did I wrong?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please add an example of ($dateEx - 25569)*24*60*60

Comment: Convert both strings to time. Using `strtotime`. Dates in versions before 4.2 can't be compared

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer, formats are valid recording to ISO8601 Notations (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: from excel I get numbers like this 42164.536761227 instead of dates

Comment: And what does the second argument of date contains after your calculation?

Comment: why not just convert them all up to datetime objects then make your comparisons

Comment: the value from Excel I get is a date value like my strings what I get after this     $date = date('Ymd',($dateEx - 25569)*24*60*60); is this 20150331

Comment: @Ghost: I already tried to convert them all to datetime but it didnt work

Comment: Please see my answer, i think that's the solution

Comment: @sarikaya yes you used datetime, but you're comparing the `->format`ted string, directly convert the constructed object, use the object, it'll work, convert `$date` to datetime also, then make your comparisons

Answer (score 2):

> from excel I get numbers like this 42164.536761227 instead of dates

Those numbers are MS Excel serialized timestamp values

This is why PHPExcel provides functions to convert between MS Excel serialized timestamp values and PHP DateTime objects or Unix timestamps (and vice versa)

```
$dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(42164.536761227);
echo $dateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(42164.536761227);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTimestamp);
```

You can then use standard PHP functions to do any comparisons

Comment: In the second example, it's actually PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(42164.536761227);

Answer (score 1):

PHP date functions accepts a timestamp as second argument, no ISO8601 date format. Strtotime does accept that, and returns a valid timestamp. Combine the two like this:

```
$dateEx = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$line)->getValue();
$iso8601Date = ($dateEx - 25569)*24*60*60;    
$date = new DateTime($iso8601Date);
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) link for more about date formats

Compare the DateTime objects

```
$dateOuverture = '20150306';
$dateFerm = '20150906';

$dateOuverture = new Datetime($dateOuverture);
$dateFerm = new Datetime($dateFerm);

if($date<=$dateFerm && $date>=$dateOuverture){
    echo "Im in the if";
}
```

Comment: Try comparing two datetime objects. See my edit and this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8