# Get time difference & User Information using php

Tags: php

Please, i need to get the time difference between a particular time and the current time. ie. I want to track users who submit an assignment late. the deadline time is 10:00AM everyday.I have surf,but all the solution i am seeing does not seems to work. see below:

```
<?php

   $d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d 10:00:00'));//Deadline time
   $d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));//Submission time
   $interval = $d1->diff($d2);
   $c = $interval->minute;
   if($c>0){
  echo "submitted late";}else{ echo "Submitted on time";}
?>
```

Comment: Use `while loop` for fetching all email and for SELECT query use use `mysqli_num_rows()` to check number of rows  return by your query

Comment: @Saty: How shoudl i do this, becuase i know i can use: while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($q){ }. How shoud i write such that it will return ALL as a single line even if i have to concatenate. Show me please

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Just use one query for that `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emailadd) FROM table_email WHERE owner='Nelson'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql

Comment: This is just one minute search.

Comment: Please one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first point, your code doesn't work because $interval->minute is always positive. So you should simply compare two dates.
Use the following code to achieve it:

```
    $d1 = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d 10:00:00'));//Deadline time
    $d2 = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));//Submission time
    if($d1 < $d2) {
        echo "submitted late";
    } else { 
        echo "Submitted on time";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$deadline = date('10:00:00');
$now      = date('H:i:s');

if($now > $deadline){
    echo "submitted late";
} else { 
    echo "Submitted on time";
}
```

as simple as that

Comment: this code seems to work, but I think, since i am comparing the deadline time with the current time, it shoud be (current time>deadline time) echo Submitted late else Submitted on time. because it is given the same output of submitted late especially when you compare 9:30 with 10:00. what coudl be the issue?

Comment: this is why you should geve meaningful names to variables - not to confuse them. Now it's clear

Comment: @So, what is the Solution:, as the time is still not working...,becuase, changing the time to 1 minue to 10am, still shows late submission.

Comment: @Did you try changing your time like 9:25 and see the response? A it is showing the submission late here? Finally, how can i prevent users from changing their clock to lower time before submission?

Comment: Users' clock has nothing to do with your server. the latter edited code in my answer shows the right message for the any time given