# how to compare between two times in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare between two times: the `$now_time` and `$finish_time`.
the `$finish_time` is +100 minute after `$starting_time`.
i want to add if else on this times to do: if `$now_time` is more than `$finitsh_time` the result echo `true`, else echo `false`

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
    $now_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

    $starting_time = "2020-02-08 20:30:00";
    $finish_time = strtotime("+100 minutes", strtotime($starting_time));

    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $now_time);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $finish_time);

    if($date1 < $date2){
        echo "True";
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare two DateTime objects in PHP 5.2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8)

Comment: yeah, just with a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `DateTime` class you could simplify the above code a little:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$starting_time = '2020-02-08 20:30:00';


$start=new DateTime( $starting_time );
$end=new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( sprintf( '%s+100minutes', $start->format('y-m-d H:i:s') ) ) ) );

if( $start < $end )echo 'True';
else echo 'False';
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider. Ive added the `now` to your solution and its work how i wants

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the binary format and only to use human printable dates only for input from and output to user interface. That make programming easier and the  code is more efficient -- calculations with broken down dates are time intensive.

So my solution:

```
# not needed here
# date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
# $now_time = time();

# This is the only text-to-bin conversion
$starting_time = strtotime("2020-02-08 20:30:00");
$finish_time = $starting_time + 100*60; // + 100 minutes

# differences and comparing binary times is very easy and efficient
if ( $starting_time < $finish_time ) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```