# Form calculation fails

Tags: php

We're trying to fix the PHP code (from php programmer who was fired few weeks ago) to make sure these dates does not exceed more than 28 days on the form.

When the customer fills out the application on the https://www.sorensonvrs.com/international_travel_request and they fill it out over 28 days -  it fails.

[image: Failed]

PHP -

```
if ($valid_departure_date == TRUE && $valid_return_date == TRUE) {
       $submit_date = intval(date("Ymd"));  // Today's date
       $departure_date_string = sprintf("%02d",$post['departureYear']).sprintf("%02d",$post['departureMonth']).sprintf("%02d",$post['departureDay']);
       $departure_date = intval($departure_date_string);
       $return_date_string = sprintf("%02d",$post['returnYear']).sprintf("%02d",$post['returnMonth']).sprintf("%02d",$post['returnDay']);
       $return_date = intval($return_date_string);
       if ($departure_date > $return_date) {
         // $this->errors += array('depGTRet' => 'required');
         $this->errors = $post->errors();
         $post->add_error('depGTRet','required');
         $this->valid = '';
       } else {
         if ($submit_date >= $departure_date) {
           // $this->errors += array('oldDates' => 'required');
           $post->add_error('oldDates','required');
           $this->errors = $post->errors();
           $this->valid = '';
         } else {
           $trip_departure_date = substr($departure_date,0,4) . '-' .  substr($departure_date,4,2) . '-' .  substr($departure_date,6,2);
           $trip_return_date = date_create($trip_departure_date);
           date_add($trip_return_date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("28 days"));
           $trip_return_date = intval(date_format($trip_return_date,"Ymd"));
           if ($return_date >= $trip_return_date) {
             // $this->errors += array('checkDates' => 'required');
             $this->errors = $post->errors();
             $post->add_error('checkDates','required');
             $this->valid = '';
           } else {
             $validated_dates = TRUE;
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

We're not a math whiz, but these calculation in PHP is confusing us. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Looks like the perfect moment to write some test cases for that function

Comment: We do not have a php progammer anymore. Hes gone. Thats the problem

Comment: Then you should look up a freelancer for a short-term solution and a replacement for the long run. I don't want to be rude, but you cannot expect anybody to understand that code and just guess where it is going wrong

Comment: Its a LIVE site and we get customers applying online almost daily and thought we would check out with you guys who can check it out real quick.

Comment: `$post` should be `$_POST`.

Comment: I think $post is an variable being set.

Comment: Take a moment and read up on [DateTime objects and date comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8)

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code? If it's being displayed while the user fills in the form, the check is in JavaScript on the client.

Comment: Its when the submit button is hit the error message appears as shown on the screenshot.