# PHP custom sort function of multidimensional array because of usort members equality problem

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem sorting some arrays because some comparing values are the same and usort can't be controlled in which order those should be returned. This is a limitation of usort which I can't overcome unless I use some custom sorting function. This is where I need the help.

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/01/2021
            [time] => 15:25
            [name] => name1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/01/2021
            [time] => 15:27
            [name] => name2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 26/01/2021
            [time] => 07:19
            [name] => name3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 26/01/2021
            [time] => 07:24
            [name] => name4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 08:38
            [name] => name5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 08:38
            [name] => name6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 10:09
            [name] => name7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 16:40
            [name] => name8
        )
)
```

I want to sort the array in chronologial order (newest to oldest) but as you can see name5 and name6 have the same date and time. I want these to be returned in the order they appear (the smallest key first).

What I would like as an outcome for example in this specific array is a reverse order (since they are in oldest to newest) but name5 and name6 not to be reversed (because I want to keep the order they are in).

How can I do this? Not specifically for this table, but maybe on another table where 3 items have the same date/time.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort multidimensional array by multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232965/sort-multidimensional-array-by-multiple-keys)

Comment: You really should store dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format (or even `yyyy/mm/dd`), then you can sort them as strings instead of having to parse them into dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( $arr as $i => &$x ){ $x['k'] = $i; }
```

This adds a column to contain the key you're wanting to sort by. Then, just do your usort operation, that falls back to the key compare if date/time is equal. I added a simple helper function to fix your dates so strtotime can parse it.

```
function o_to_time( $o ){
    return strtotime( implode( "/" , array_reverse( explode( "/" , $o["date"] ) ) ) . " " . $o["time"] );
}

usort( $arr , function( $a , $b ){
    return o_to_time( $b ) <=> o_to_time( $a ) ?: $a['k'] <=> $b['k'];
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this we need to implement a function that compares the date and time and return 0, -1, or 1. This way [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will be able to sort the array. When the return is 0 the position is not changed.

Input:

```
  $arr = [
    ['date' => '23/01/2021', 'time' => '15:25', 'name' => ' name1'],
    ['date' => '23/01/2021', 'time' => '15:27', 'name' => ' name2'],
    ['date' => '26/01/2021', 'time' => '07:19', 'name' => ' name3'],
    ['date' => '26/01/2021', 'time' => '07:24', 'name' => ' name4'],
    ['date' => '27/01/2021', 'time' => '08:38', 'name' => ' name5'],
    ['date' => '27/01/2021', 'time' => '08:38', 'name' => ' name6'],
    ['date' => '27/01/2021', 'time' => '10:09', 'name' => ' name7'],
    ['date' => '27/01/2021', 'time' => '16:14', 'name' => ' name8']
  ];
```

In the callback function we pass to `usort` we will convert the date and time in the input array to a DateTime object so we can compare the dates. Here is a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961116/7501641) on how to compare DateTime objects

The DateTime class has a static function [DateTime.createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) that you can pass the format of the string you want to convert to a DateTime, in your case `d/m/Y H:i` (23/01/2021 15:25).

To order it from oldest to newest:

```
  usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $dateTimeA = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', "{$a['date']} {$a['time']}");
    $dateTimeB = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', "{$b['date']} {$b['time']}");

    if($dateTimeA == $dateTimeB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($dateTimeA > $dateTimeB) ? -1 : 1;
  });
```

To order it from newest to oldest just change `>` to `<` in the return statement:

```
  return ($dateTimeA < $dateTimeB) ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't work as intended - it doesn't handle the scenario where values are the same correctly?

Comment: It only _works_ if the keys are in the right order already. If you flip the order of the two items on input (but leave the keys as they are) then it doesn't sort them as it should do.

Comment: I see what you mean. The name key. That is true I did not take that into consideration but that is easy to add to that logic.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case of `uksort`...

You need to use some sort of function to sort the date/times, I'd just use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and create the string from the `date` and `time` fields.

Obviously you need to check first if they're the same and if they are sort based on the keys...

Then if they aren't the same use the *spaceship operator* (`<=>`) to return `-1|0|1` depending on the whether the value (`DateTime` object) on the left is smaller, the same, or greater than the one on the right - obviously it won't return `0` in this case because we already took care of that.

**Input**

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
            'date' => '23/01/2021',
            'time' => '15:25',
            'name' => 'name1',
        ],

    1 => [
            'date' => '23/01/2021',
            'time' => '15:27',
            'name' => 'name2',
        ],

    2 => [
            'date' => '26/01/2021',
            'time' => '07:19',
            'name' => 'name3',
        ],

    3 => [
            'date' => '26/01/2021',
            'time' => '07:24',
            'name' => 'name4',
        ],

    4 => [
            'date' => '27/01/2021',
            'time' => '08:38',
            'name' => 'name5',
        ],
    
    5 => [
            'date' => '27/01/2021',
            'time' => '08:38',
            'name' => 'name6',
        ],

    6 => [
            'date' => '27/01/2021',
            'time' => '10:09',
            'name' => 'name7',
        ],

    7 => [
            'date' => '27/01/2021',
            'time' => '16:40',
            'name' => 'name8',
        ],
];
```

**Code**

```
uksort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($arr){
    $aDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", "{$arr[$a]["date"]} {$arr[$a]["time"]}");
    $bDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", "{$arr[$b]["date"]} {$arr[$b]["time"]}");

    if($aDate == $bDate){
        return $a <=> $b;
    }

    return $bDate <=> $aDate;
});

print_r($arr);
```

**Compacted Code**

```
uksort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($arr){
    $aDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", "{$arr[$a]["date"]} {$arr[$a]["time"]}");
    $bDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", "{$arr[$b]["date"]} {$arr[$b]["time"]}");

    return $aDate == $bDate ? $a <=> $b : $bDate <=> $aDate;
});
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 16:40
            [name] => name8
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 10:09
            [name] => name7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 08:38
            [name] => name5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27/01/2021
            [time] => 08:38
            [name] => name6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 26/01/2021
            [time] => 07:24
            [name] => name4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 26/01/2021
            [time] => 07:19
            [name] => name3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/01/2021
            [time] => 15:27
            [name] => name2
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/01/2021
            [time] => 15:25
            [name] => name1
        )

)
```

Comment: The `$aDate == $bDate` check is not necessary.  The spaceship operator already handles `==` in its "3-way comparison".